# Push String into Array in Array at certain position

Tags: arrays, node.js, push

How can I push a String into an array that is in an array?

```
var outerArray = [[]]

outerArray.push('test1')
outerArray.push('test2')

outerArray[0] = outerArray[0].push('test3')

console.log(outerArray[0][0])
```

this just returns `undefined`

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work :-/

Comment: @FabianLauer oups, updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to create an array at position 0 including the previous item at that index and a new one. This will work:

```
outerArray[0] = [outerArray[0], 'test3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const innerArray = outerArray[0];
const pushedString = innerArray.push('testString');
```

Also, as you know, push returns an item that has been pushed.